# Restarting Jboss eap using jenkins without root permission on remote host

Tags: java, linux, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jboss-eap-6

I have configured jenkins to copy the jar file generated from the job to target folder on remote host(GNU LINUX) where jboss is running. Presently I have to manually restart the jboss every time for the changes to reflect. I am using scp only account and jenkins scp plugin for jar movement.

Is there a way we can restart the jboss from jenkins without root access on the remote host where jboss is running so that this completely automates the process. The scp account I have on the remote only has copy persmissions. I cannot execute a shell.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you using maven to build your jar file? Is the jar file a deployment artefact or are you using JBoss Modules?

Comment: Hi Steve. I used maven to build the jar file and move it to JBoss Modules folder. Not a deployment artifact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to use [wildfly:shutdown](https://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/latest/shutdown-mojo.html) (with the `reload` option) to achieve the effect of a restart in JBoss EAP 6.x.

The success of this may depend on the accessibility of the control port, so an SSH tunnel may be needed. I'm not sure if you can achieve this in your environment though.

Try to get it working on a JBoss EAP instance running on an accessible LAN first.